# Slide out menu with slide over submenus in js

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in JavaScript, and I'm trying to create a `slide out menu with slide over submenus`. Unfortunately, I can't find any JavaScript examples (without jQuery) to inspire me and understand how to create this.

I absolutely want to achieve something like the example below, except it's done in jQuery. Do you think it's possible to do this in JavaScript?

https://codepen.io/suzannah_h/pen/QWLXvbx